# How do I create a link in Excel, with a formula in it, to another Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure if this is even possible in Excel but this is what I need to do:

I have a column with a list of hotels and then another column which needs to pull data from each individual hotel's excel file. For example, cell A2 will have the name "Paris" for the hotel and then cell B2 will have the link:

```
  ='G:\Hotels\Paris\Paris - Monthly\[Paris_summary_2018.xlsm]Feb'!$CD$89
```

I have lots of hotels I need to do this for in different sheets. So I need the link to dynamically refer to whatever hotel is in column A and the title of the sheet, for example could I do something like this?

```
=''G:\Hotels\A2\A2 - Monthly\[A2_summary_2018.xlsm]Feb'!$CD$89
```

where A2 has the string "Paris". Also is there a way to dynamically refer to "Feb" depending on what sheet I am in the month will be the title

I am also open to using VBA for this.

Comment: I think with normal Excel is not possible, but with VBA indeed. Try checking [Excel VBA to make hyperlink for active cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445182/excel-vba-to-make-hyperlink-for-active-cell) and maybe you can get on the road to what you want

Comment: Would something like what's described here be similar to what you want to do? https://superuser.com/questions/489089/can-excel-use-formula-input-data-for-cell-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't mind using VBA, you can easily generate the links with something like this:

```
Sub generate_hotel_links()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Dim s As String
    ' This is the range which all the hotel-locations are in
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In r
        ' Generate the formula based on the current cell we are in
        s = "=" & Chr(39) & "G:\Hotels\" & CStr(c) & "\" & CStr(c) & " - Monthly\[" & CStr(c) & "_summary_2018.xlsm]Feb" & Chr(39) & "!$CD$89"
        ' ...and put it in the neighbouring cell
        c.Offset(0, 1).Formula = s
    Next c
    On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```

`On Error Resume Next` will make the macro continue no matter what error pops up - the ideal case would be some more robust error handling, or a check for if the workbook / sheet actually exists before attempting to write the formula, but I'll leave it to you to attempt to write this if you feel the need improve the macro.

If you want to just use generic Excel formulas, I'd advice having a look at the question and answers I posted in the comments to your question.

Comment: This works great! However, how can I get the macro to move on if it can't find the external workbook? I tried On error resume after For Each but it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: @Sorath I added the easiest solution to my answer. Note that this will skip all errors, so if something unexpected happens you may not get to learn about it. I'd advise more robust error handling, but without knowing more about your exact situation, I don't want to go into any more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use `HYPERLINK`.

Like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("G:\Hotels\"&A2&"\"&A2&" - Monthly\["&A2&"_summary_2018.xlsm]Feb!"&$CD$89)
```

Comment: I tried on my excel and I got it working. Did you copy my function? And could it be the excel version? I am still using 2010...

Comment: I am using 2013. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working

Comment: What is on your cell A2? Is it the text 'Paris'? if you set a cell content to `=A2` what do you get? And then another to `=CD89` . Probably the problem is on those cells and not on the formula. And maybe you can try `CONCATENATE`